# HTAccess ReWrite Rules Conflicting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two re-write rules one as a vanity url so for example domain.com/url and one to edit some a data aka post.

For some reason only the first rule is taking place and not both

Why is that and how can I fix it??

Here's The Code

```
RewriteEngine On

# Make sure you only match on files/directories that don't actually exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite the first part after the `/` into a `username` parameter

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ groups/index.php?gname=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^edit/id/([0-9]+)/?$ groups/view_update.php?pid=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule` not to all the `RewriteRule`. Also change order of your rules.

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Make sure you only match on files/directories that don't actually exist
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite the first part after the `/` into a `username` parameter

# skip all rewrite rules for file or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^edit/id/([0-9]+)/?$ groups/view_update.php?pid=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ groups/index.php?gname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: tried sill the same issue :( very annoying and thanks so far

Edit: Nevermind got it working :D by just changing the re-wrtie rules around :D